# Using Input Number to Create Paragraph with Unique ID's

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a little stuck here with a JavaScript issue. I'm trying to make an input number field manipulate the number of times a paragraph is created, which I have working. The area where I'm a little stuck is getting it to give each paragraph a unique id and add to the content text number.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this as at the moment it's creating each paragraph with the same id and the same content text number?

```js
function updatePage() {
  // Get input value
  var numberInput = document.getElementById("numberInput").value;

  // Will be used to store all <p> contents
  var template = "";

  while (numberInput > 0) {
    // Add all contents into template
    template += '<p id="p1">Content - 1<p/><br>';

    numberInput--;
  }
  // Append upon clicking
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = template;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" id="numberInput">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="updatePage()">
<div id="content">
  <p id="p1">Content - 1<p/><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this:
(*Just concat the **numberInput** in the **id** and the **Template**.*)

```js
function updatePage() {
  // Get input value
  var numberInput = document.getElementById("numberInput").value;

  // Will be used to store all <p> contents
  var template = "";
  var idx = 1 
  while (idx <= numberInput ) {
    // Add all contents into template
    template += '<p id="p' +idx + '">Content - ' + idx  + '<p/><br>';
    
    idx++;
  }
  // Append upon clicking
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = template;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" id="numberInput">
<br />
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="updatePage()">
<div id="content">
  <p id="p1">Content - 1<p/><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make them display in chronological order rather than `5,4,3,2,1` then present `1,2,3,4,5`?

Answer (score 0):

Concat the input value like this `'<p id="p_'+numberInput+'">`

```js
function updatePage() {
  // Get input value
  var numberInput = document.getElementById("numberInput").value;

  // Will be used to store all <p> contents
  var template = "";

  while (numberInput > 0) {
    // Add all contents into template
    template += '<p id="p_' + numberInput + '">Content - 1<p/><br>';

    numberInput--;
  }
  // Append upon clicking
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = template;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" id="numberInput">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="updatePage()">
<div id="content">
  <p id="p1">Content - 1
    <p/><br>
</div>
```